# Load user control into RadToolTip?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, telerik, tooltip

I'm trying to load a user control into a `RadToolTip` upon button click. Once I click the button, I want to load the user control and then call the control's `Initialize` method, passing a collection of objects I have stored in the page viewstate.

Here is the `RadToolTip` markup:

```
<telerik:RadToolTip runat="server" ID="_MyToolTip" HideEvent="ManualClose" 
    Position="Center" Width="500px" Height="400px" Animation="Fade"
    ShowEvent="OnClick" ShowDelay="0" RelativeTo="Element"
    TargetControlID="_MySelectButton" RenderInPageRoot="True" />
```

Here is the `Click` event handler for `MyButton`:

```
protected void _MySelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl(@"~/UserControls/MyUserControl.ascx");

    var muc = (ctrl as MyUserControlClass);

    muc.Initialize(_MyViewStateCollection); 
}
```

I want it so that when `_MySelectButton_Click` fires, it will create a new instance of `MyUserControl`, and then that event will propagate up into the `RadToolTip` so that the tooltip appears, and then the user control within the tooltip. However, right now only the `RadToolTip` appears, with no user control within it.

I found [this post](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tooltip-troubleshooting-common-issues.html) on Telerik's site which states:

> **Click events are not fired for a tooltipified element**
>
> The RadToolTip registers event handlers for the client-side events and
>   therefore they cancel the further click propagation so that the
>   tooltip remains visible, as a postback would hide it. **This means
>   that when the ShowEvent is set to OnClick elements such as Buttons,
>   CheckBoxes, RadioButtons, LinkButtons may not fire their server events
>   or even their client-side behavior may change** (espeacially for the
>   RadioButton and CheckBox - they will not change their states, as the
>   click is cancelled). To avoid this set the ShowEvent to OnFocus or to
>   OnMouseOver, for example. The same holds true for the
>   RadToolTipManager as well.

If the problem is that the button's `Click` is essentially incompatible given that the `RadToolTip` is preventing the click from propagating, how can I achieve the desired behavior? **Bottom line, I want to be able to click a button, open a tooltip, then open my user control within that tooltip.** Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/two-radtooltipmanager-on-same-page) on Telerik's site where someone was having issues having two `RadToolTipManager` objects on the same page.

As I've been trying to add the `RadToolTip` to a page with an already existing `RadToolTipManager`, I decided to change my `RadToolTip` into an additional `RadToolTipManager` and explicitly specify the `TargetControlID` to reference `_MySelectButton`, and now the button click produces the tooltip along with the expected user control elements.

```
<telerik:RadToolTipManager runat="server" ID="_MyToolTipManager"
    OffsetY="-1" OffsetX="250" HideEvent="ManualClose" Width="500" Height="400"
    RelativeTo="Element" RenderInPageRoot="True"
    OnAjaxUpdate="MySelectButtonToolTipManagerAjaxUpdate"
    ShowEvent="OnClick" Animation="Slide">

    <TargetControls>
        <telerik:ToolTipTargetControl TargetControlID="_MySelectButton" />
    </TargetControls>

</telerik:RadToolTipManager>
```

Here is the associated handler for the `RadToolTipManager`'s `OnAjaxUpdate` event:

```
protected void MySelectButtonToolTipManagerAjaxUpdate(
    object sender, ToolTipUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl(@"~/UserControls/MyUserControl.ascx");
    ctrl.ID = "MyUserControl";
    e.UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(ctrl);           
    var li = (ctrl as MyUserControlClass);

    li.Initialize(MyViewStateCollection);
}
```

**Problem solved!**